# Add collectives to other sites

Tags: feature-request, collectives

On Stack Overflow, there are something called [Collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/help/collectives-what-are). Collectives are a way of organising information on different topics related to the site. However, I would like to see collectives on other sites. Here are some examples of how they could be used:

- A [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) Collective on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)
- Collectives for golfing languages on [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Can you please add collectives to other sites?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, Collectives are a magnet for off-topic questions, so some caution is warranted.

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer I can only speak for myself, but [collectives weren't well recieved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408585/beta-release-of-collectives-on-stack-overflow) (+133/-417), and a decent number of people don't like them on Stack Overflow, and don't want them on other sites either. Again, can't speak for everyone, but I feel that tags work fine, and we don't need collectives at all. As a result, I downvoted this as I disagree with the proposal - it's not personal at all, I simply don't think this would be good, and so I disagree.

Comment: You shouldn't see this **[tag:feature-request]** score as **yours**. The score belongs to the **question/post**. Votes on [tag:feature-request] mean agreement / disagreement, as is explained in [help], so downvotes here mean that some disagree with this proposal.

Comment: @Rubén I know, I was wondering why people did not agree with my proposal, hence me asking why the downvotes.

Comment: The reason for the downvotes has been explained repeatedly to many people over many years, so please refrain from asking again. People willing to explain their disagreement in detail will do it by posting a comment or an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collectives still have to build a convincing success story. Once this happens, it might be possible to get a sponsor, internal or external.

I think that Collectives eventually will reach a stable stage. Once it reaches this stage, I think that it should follow a similar process as new site proposals follow on Area 51: before proposing a new collective, a solid user group / community should be ready to consolidate it quickly and eager to take advantage of the features offered by the "Collective" package of extra features like articles, recognized members, etc.

A Collective requires some administrative work, so someone from the user group or the sponsor should be willing and ready to handle that burn.